# Gmaps4Rails Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %=

Tags: javascript, ruby, gmaps4rails

Trying to use a separate application.js file for the page, but I'm not sure how to add the hash in the .js file. It keeps telling me "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %=" I don't think I can add ruby to that file.

application.js file

```
function createSidebarLi(json){
  return ("<li><a>" + json.name + "</a></li>");
};

function bindLiToMarker($li, marker){
  $li.on('click', function(){
    handler.getMap().setZoom(14);
    marker.setMap(handler.getMap()); //because clusterer removes map property from marker
    marker.panTo();
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click');
  })
};

function createSidebar(json_array){
  _.each(json_array, function(json){
    var $li = $( createSidebarLi(json) );
    $li.appendTo('#sidebar_container');
    bindLiToMarker($li, json.marker);
  });
};

handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'sidebar_builder'}}, function(){
  var json_array = [
    <%= raw @hash.tojson %>
  ];

  var markers = handler.addMarkers(json_array);

  _.each(json_array, function(json, index){
    json.marker = markers[index];
  });

  createSidebar(json_array);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

activated in view, but I don't see the map. Do I need to turn the entire thing into a function or does it just know to execute this? Also I am using HAML

```
%h3 Nearby locations
%ul
  - @truckuser.each do |storeuser|
    %li
      = link_to storeuser.truckname, profile_path(storeuser)
      (#{storeuser.distance.round(2)} miles)
%body{:onload => "getLocation()"}      
  %div{:style => "width: 800px;"}
    #map{:style => "width: 800px; height: 400px;"}
```

Comment: No, you cannot add ruby to a `.js` file.

Comment: I realize that. I am asking what alternative I have rather than placing the script in my html.erb page.

Comment: I'm sorry I cant help you through stack overflow, but I think you still dont grasp js enough so it's hard to explain from scratch without talking.

Comment: it's fine. I got it figured out I think. I'm onto a new project now though. Thanks!